# Unique tasks all along a program

Tags: java, algorithm, optimization, set

In my program, I do some tasks, parametrized by a `MyParameter` object (I call `doTask(MyParameter parameter)` to run a task).

From the beginning to the end of the program, I can create a lot of tasks (a few million at least) BUT i want to run **only once** each of them (if a task has already been executed, the method does nothing)

Currently, I'm using a `HashSet` to store the `MyParameter` objects for the tasks already executed, but if the `MyParameter` object is 100bytes, and if I run in my program 10M tasks, it is 1GB at least in memory ...)

How can I optimize that, to use as few memory as possible ?

Thanks a lot guys

Comment: do your tasks run in parallel? Can't you just create - execute - destroy?

Comment: Why do you need to store your MyParameter objects after the task? Do they contain any results? If your biggest concern right now is to use less memory, can't you just serialize the MyParameter objects and write them on the disk or in a DB?

Answer (score 1):

If all you need to know is whether a particular `MyParameter` has been processed or not, ditch the `HashSet` and use a [`BitSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html) instead.

Basically, if all you need to know is whether a particular `MyParameter` is done or not, then storing the entire `MyParameter` in the set is overkill - you only need to store a single bit, where `0` means "not done" and `1` means "done". This is exactly what a `BitSet` is designed for.

The hashes of your `MyParameter` values are presumably unique, otherwise your current approach of using a `HashSet` is pointless. If so, then you can use the `hashCode()` of each `MyParameter` as an index into the bit set, using the corresponding bit as an indicator of whether the given `MyParameter` is done or not.

That probably doesn't make much sense as is, so the following is a basic implementation. (Feel free to substitute the `for` loop, `numParameters`, `getParameter()`, etc with whatever it is that you're actually using to generate `MyParameter`s)

```
BitSet doneSet = new BitSet();

for (int i = 0; < numParameters; ++i) {
    MyParameter parameter = getParameter(i);

    if (!doneSet.get(parameter.hashCode())) {
        doTask(parameter );
        doneSet.set(parameter.hashCode());
    }
}
```

The memory usage of this approach is a bit contingent on how `BitSet` is implemented internally, but I would expect it to be significantly better than simply storing all your `MyParameters` in a `HashSet`.

If, in fact, you do need to hang onto your `MyParameter` objects once you've processed them because they contain the result of processing, then you can possibly save space by storing just the result portion of the `MyParameter` in the `HashSet` (if such a thing's possible - your question doesn't make this clear).

If, on the other hand, you really do need each `MyParameter` in its entirety once you're done processing it, then you're already doing pretty much the best you can do. You might be able to do a little better memory-wise by storing them as a vector (i.e. expandable array) of `MyParameters` (which avoids some of the memory overheads inherent in using a `HashSet`), but this will incur a speed penalty due to time needed to expand the vector and an O(n) search time.

Comment: I don't need to have the value of the already computed 'MyParameter'

The only problem I can see with the Bitset is the collision problem.

But otherwise, it's a good idea :)

Comment: As I implied in the answer, I was assuming you're pretty confident that there will be few hash collisions, otherwise you probably wouldn't be using a `HashSet` (since its performance relies on there being relatively few collisions). It's hard to say for sure without knowing more about your data, but you should (in theory) be able to derive an optimal `hashCode()` implementation for your `MyParameter` class that reduces (or even eliminates) the risk of collisions.

Answer (score 0):

A TreeSet will give you somewhat better memory performance than a HashSet, at the cost of log(n) lookups.

You can use a NoSql key-value store such as [Cassandra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Cassandra) or [LevelDB](https://github.com/dain/leveldb), which are essentially external hash tables.

You may be able to compress the `MyParameter` representation, but if it's only at 100bytes currently then I don't know how much smaller you'd be able to get it.